# Tez crashes on HDP 2.1

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

my hive crashes when i try to run a TEZ job in the terminal. I have installed HDP 2.1 on a cluster with 5 nodes. OS: Redhat Enterprise

Who can help me? :)

Log from Application tracker:

```
HDP: 2.1
User: hdfs
Name: HIVE-9fd632e5-d76a-4e0a-8845-0c1f0af52f5c
Application Type: TEZ
Application Tags:
State: FAILED
FinalStatus: FAILED
Started: 1-Jul-2014 12:03:22
Elapsed: 4sec
Tracking URL: History
Diagnostics:
Application application_1404208879507_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for    appattempt_1404208879507_0002_000002 exited with exitCode: 1 due to: Exception from container-    launch:     org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException:
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
at         org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecu    tor.java:195)
at     org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch    .java:300)
at     org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch    .java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.
```

And in the terminal:

```
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Tez session was closed. Reopening...
Session re-established.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be that the ID of the user running the job cannot be less than 1000. Go to the log files of the TaskTracker to see if there is a message like:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Reading task con­troller configuration /etc/hadoop/taskcontroller.cfg
INFO. org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: requested user
hdfs has id 201, which is below the minimum allowed 1000
```

If that is the case, then you can do the following:

```
usermod -u 10000 hdfs
```

Comment: Sorry did not work, i edited my post with more info :)

Comment: I think Tez is just very unstable. Only select * from without where clausules are working at the moment.. I logged in as HDFS on Hue and fired a normal select * from ... query. Thanks for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think Tez is just very unstable. Only select * from without where clausules are working at the moment.. I logged in as HDFS on Hue and fired a normal select * from ... query. Thanks for your quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

The line "Application application_1404208879507_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for" shows that the Tez Application Master likely failed to launch. This could be due to various reasons.

The simplest place to look for the reason is the application logs obtained by invoking "bin/yarn logs -applicationId application_1404208879507_0002". The most common issue causing this is usually some setup/configuration error leading to ClassNotFound errors when launching the java process.